# Keeping my remote Job with MSC in Berlin

Tags: masters, remote-work

I am born & live in Uganda, and I got an opportunity to study MSC in Computer Science in Berlin while also having a remote job with a company in Egypt at the moment which pays me very well.

Now I have been chasing this MSC for a while now long before I got my remote Job, I had actually given up on it as I thought it would never happen. But then right now, I have this great Job which I do not also want to loose at the same time.

I am very confused at this point as I look at my self as someone who wants to eat my cake & have it.   So my question is, what are the disadvantages of keeping my full time remote job & still being in school with all the course work & everything.

I might feel really depressed if I have bad grades. Should I just let the MSC go & move on?

Comment: Apart from time management, visa rules may limit how and how much you can work. You might want to research that before committing, or ask about it over at [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both at the same time seems quite unfeasible. A degree in Germany is generally considered to be a full time thing by itself, not to mention the additional work of living in a foreign country, having to deal with German immigration and bureaucracy (which apparently is a special nightmare in Berlin).

I would say the question boils down to where you want to be in five years. If you can see yourself living and working full time in Germany, then the M.Sc. is the clear way to go. As far as I know, if you finish a degree on a student visa, you can to transform it into a work permit if you can find a job within a few months afterwards. If you want to ultimately stay in Uganda, then maybe keeping the job is better. But I don't know how much a European degree is valued there and if it could get you an even better job.

If you really need the money, asking the company to reduce your hours might be another option, but if you go your time is best spent studying (and possibly learning German).

Comment: I'll ask my company to reduce my hours to 20 hours per week & I'll see how that goes. If it doesn't go well, I'll just resign then.